# IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity/InvocationTargetException

Tags: android

My APP's main activity act as a feature selector with many buttons on layout. I got this error after I add another feature ,and it shouldn't be relative to the other old features for the separating architecture of main activity. Before that, two activity below ran well. What's the points I missed?

```
Main: IPTV_Wallpaper
RSS: RSSDisplayerMain
Map: HealthMapMain
```

Here is logcat:
Logcat for a RSS Reader Activity

```
06-23 16:15:00.332: E/AndroidRuntime(3124): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-23 16:15:00.332: E/AndroidRuntime(3124): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-23 16:15:00.332: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3597)
06-23 16:15:00.332: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
06-23 16:15:00.332: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17341)
06-23 16:15:00.332: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-23 16:15:00.332: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-23 16:15:00.332: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-23 16:15:00.332: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
06-23 16:15:00.332: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 16:15:00.332: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-23 16:15:00.332: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-23 16:15:00.332: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-23 16:15:00.332: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-23 16:15:00.332: E/AndroidRuntime(3124): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-23 16:15:00.332: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 16:15:00.332: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-23 16:15:00.332: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3592)
06-23 16:15:00.332: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     ... 11 more
06-23 16:15:00.332: E/AndroidRuntime(3124): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: tw.danny.idcc_hw2.RSSDisplayerMain
06-23 16:15:00.332: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     at tw.danny.iptv_1.IPTV_Wallpaper.NewsReader(IPTV_Wallpaper.java:116)
06-23 16:15:00.332: E/AndroidRuntime(3124):     ... 14 more
```

Logcat for a google map API Activity

```
06-23 16:15:49.582: E/dalvikvm(3143): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng', referenced from method tw.danny.healthmap.HealthMapMain.<clinit>
06-23 16:15:49.582: E/dalvikvm(3143): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions', referenced from method tw.danny.healthmap.HealthMapMain.MarkOnMap
06-23 16:15:49.592: E/AndroidRuntime(3143): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-23 16:15:49.592: E/AndroidRuntime(3143): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
06-23 16:15:49.592: E/AndroidRuntime(3143):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
06-23 16:15:49.592: E/AndroidRuntime(3143):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
06-23 16:15:49.592: E/AndroidRuntime(3143):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
06-23 16:15:49.592: E/AndroidRuntime(3143):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
06-23 16:15:49.592: E/AndroidRuntime(3143):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-23 16:15:49.592: E/AndroidRuntime(3143):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-23 16:15:49.592: E/AndroidRuntime(3143):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-23 16:15:49.592: E/AndroidRuntime(3143):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-23 16:15:49.592: E/AndroidRuntime(3143):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-23 16:15:49.592: E/AndroidRuntime(3143):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
06-23 16:15:49.592: E/AndroidRuntime(3143):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 16:15:49.592: E/AndroidRuntime(3143):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-23 16:15:49.592: E/AndroidRuntime(3143):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-23 16:15:49.592: E/AndroidRuntime(3143):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-23 16:15:49.592: E/AndroidRuntime(3143):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-23 16:15:49.592: E/AndroidRuntime(3143): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
06-23 16:15:49.592: E/AndroidRuntime(3143):     at tw.danny.healthmap.HealthMapMain.<clinit>(HealthMapMain.java:36)
06-23 16:15:49.592: E/AndroidRuntime(3143):     ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you right click your project, go to `Java Build Path` > `Order and export` and check that the libraries that you are using are checked to be exported.

Comment: After updating Android sdk and eclipse, you may encounter similar problems. You need to check the setting above, and make sure whether the lib you used was updated or not